# Get pk of foreign key from object when rendering detail view

Tags: django, django-views, django-class-based-views

Im trying to get the id of the foreign key relationship to perform to filter through a list of models. However Im getting an error that states: 'ForwardManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'id'. Is this the right way to go about this problem or am I missing something in my understanding of how all this works?

#### I created a detail view from this model:

```
class Collection(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=True)
  slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True)
  category = models.ForeignKey(Category)

  @models.permalink
  def get_absolute_url(self):
    return ('collection_detail', (),
            {
                'slug' :self.slug,
            })


  def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%s %s  ' % (self.category.id, self.title
                               )
```

#### This is the code from the detail view:

```
class collection_detail(DetailView):
   model = Collection

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(collection_detail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    a = self.category.id
    context['collection_list'] = Product.objects.filter(categories=a).order_by('id')
    return context
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `self.category.id` to `self.object.category.id`.

[The documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview) states:

> While this view is executing, `self.object` will contain the object that the view is operating upon.

Comment: Although you can also just use `categories=self.object` without resolving to the ID. Assuming I'm not forgetting something embarrassing.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper, good point (though I think you mean `categories=self.object.category`).

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper That works too, categories=self.object.category.id

Comment: Yes, `self.object.category` is right, thanks. The point is that Django query filters can follow foreign key relationships without specifying the `.id` part - `categories=self.object.category` rather than `categories=self.object.category.id`.